Проблема установки Let's Encript
Есть доступ к сайту только по фтп.
Попросили поставить ssl бесплатный.
Делаю через certbot на своем пк.  Домен domain.ru и www.domain.ru
Создал файлы, certbot отработал без проблем.
При попытке зайти на https://domain.ru
Получаю ошибку ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Возможно проблема в перенаправлении, которое идет по умолчанию.
domain.ru -> domain.ru/catalog

В php_info
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.56 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8) PHP/5.2.17 

Проверил через ssllabs
Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server


Пишите этот вопрос тем людям, которые обслуживают этот Apache (хостингу или что там у вас)

мне бы локализовать проблему

Очевидно, проблема где-то в районе веб-сервера, больше ей быть негде

отдал ключи техподдержки хостинга. Они поставили.
Почему не отработало у меня, не объяснили...
